# Matlab lists and cell arrays

Tags: matlab

I think this explains it better. If I have a matrix like:

```
mtx = 1 2 
      5 6
      8 4
```

I have a for loop to go through it:

```
For i = 1: size(mtx,1)
     mtx2 = mtx(i,:);
```

For every time the mtx2 is created I want to see if the first number is in a list, if it’s not I’ll check if the second is. If both of them aren’t in a list I want to put them in one.
For the first row of the example: 
`mtx2(1)` is in a list? no. How about `mtx2(2)`? no, so I create a list1 with both of them.

Comment: That depends on your application and the data, doesn't it... You don't provide a sample of `mtx` for example. Please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is your list of existing numbers?

Comment: It's created after the first row. I'm not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

This might do it

```
mtx(find(ismember(mtx,A) ==1));

ans =

5
6
```

---

**Details**

```
mtx = [1 2;     
       5 6;      
       8 4]

A = [5 6];
```

Check if `A` is a member of `mtx`

```
ismember(mtx,A)
```

ans =

```
0   0
1   1
0   0
```

Find the indices of those

```
find(ismember(mtx,A) ==1)
ans =

   2
   5
```

Then find the values of `mtx` at those indices

```
your_list  = mtx(find(ismember(mtx,A) ==1))

your_list =

   5
   6
```

Comment: But for example in the example I gave there would be 3 different lists

Comment: @Adrien Perhaps it would be helpful to edit your question with the expected output for your example.